# How To Link A Successful Login On MS-Access To A New Form

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have created a database that has coding for logging into the system but I do not know how to set a successful login to link to another form i.e. The main menu.

Below is the current code I have used, please may I be advised of the further action needed. 
Thank you

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()

If IsNull(Me.txtUsername) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter your username.", vbInformation, "Username Is Required"
    Me.txtUsername.SetFocus
Else
    If IsNull(Me.TxtPassword) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter your password.", vbInformation, "Password Is Required"
        Me.TxtPassword.SetFocus
    Else
        If (IsNull(DLookup("[Username]", "Employee_Login_Details", "[Username] ='" & Me.txtUsername.Value & "' And password = '" & Me.TxtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
            MsgBox "Incorrect username or password. Please try again.", vbInformation, "Incorrect Login Details"
        Else
            MsgBox "Correct username and password.", vbInformation, "Correct Login Details"
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
Private Sub txtUsername_Click()
```

Comment: Have a look at DoCmd.OpenForm

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to navigate to other forms from one form using DoCmd.OpenForm method. I have made some code changes, hope that helps too.

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    If Len(Me.txtUsername & vbNullString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter your username.", vbInformation, "Username Is Required"
        Me.txtUsername.SetFocus
    Else
        If Len(Me.TxtPassword & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Please enter your password.", vbInformation, "Password Is Required"
            Me.TxtPassword.SetFocus
        Else
            If DCount("*", "Employee_Login_Details", "[Username] ='" & Me.txtUsername & "' And password = '" & Me.TxtPassword & "'") = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Incorrect username or password. Please try again.", vbInformation, "Incorrect Login Details"
            Else
                MsgBox "Correct username and password.", vbInformation, "Correct Login Details"
                DoCmd.OpenForm "yourFormName"
                'Optional, but is normally a good practice to hide the Login Form over closing it down completely.'
                Me.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```